# Mixed Model Segmented Regression - different length of observation period

Tags: mixed-model, intervention-analysis

I am looking to investigate the effect of an intervention that was applied at 4 different locations. I have yearly measures of the outcome variable and the time point of the intervention is known for every location.

So far I have been looking at each location individually, conducting a segmented regression following this tutorial paper (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12174032). The idea is to have a time variable (continuous from beginning of intervention) and an indicator variable (0 for pre-intervention period, 1 for post-intervention period) and to test them for significance.

However, as I have only very few data points per locations, my idea was to conduct the analysis with the whole data set through a mixed model, choosing location as random variable.

The difficult part is that every location has a different time of observation (e.g. 1988 - 2018 vs. 1995 - 2018) and the intervention was applied at different points in time (e.g. after 8 years vs. after 10 years etc.)

Would it still be possible to pool the data and conduct and intervention analysis through segmented regression?